# NoClassDefFoundError : Android App Crashes

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror

After I have updated gradle file dependencies, My app ran into an error.
When I try to set my Edit Text

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and try to input some numbers, My app got crashed.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.insharp.payle, PID: 7694
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/view/KeyEventCompat;
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:532)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:57)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4203)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:532) 
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:57) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:315) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4203) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
E/AndroidRuntime:   Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.insharp.payle-hVY9vArgPO9gcFTOxf2IeQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5760)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1651)
                ... 6 more
E/ACRA: ACRA caught a NoClassDefFoundError exception for com.insharp.payle. Building report.
```

Here is the Exception.

I think that the error is due to KeyEventCompat which is now a deprecated class. But I couldn't find a proper solution for it.
Any help would be appreciated

Here is my edit text

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etProductQty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/register_edittext_background"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="@string/text_product_qty"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_border_2"
                />
```

My build.gradle file

```
    //    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
// compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'uk.me.lewisdeane.ldialogs:ldialogs:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
```

Comment: add you full code

Answer (score 0):

Clean your build's cache and build the project again, sometimes this happens to me when some major changes are done on a library.

If it doesn't help try invalidating caches and restarting, maybe sharing more code can help finding for the problem, with this info these are the only things that come to my mind.

Comment: I have also tried the invalidating process and I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have declared the app compat dependency.

```
 com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X
```

Comment: yes, I updated it to the new version and then the issue occured.

Comment: would you please update question with build.gradle ?